# Need SQL query to get following output. The "paid amount" & "received amount" columns are already present in table. Want to generate "invested amount"

Tags: sql-server

```
|Paid Amount | Received Amount | Invested Amount
| 10000      |    --           |  10000
|   --       |   8000          |   2000
|  5000      |    --           |   7000
|   --       |   4000          |   3000
```

Comment: At the _very_ least, you would need to also provide us with a column for ordering the transactions.

Comment: Is there any other column present to find the order ?

Comment: Provide the query that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also had a date column which ordered the transactions, you could use the following correlated subquery to find the running total:

```
SELECT
    t1.[Paid Amount],
    t1.[Received Amount],
    (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(t2.[Paid Amount], 0) - t2.[Recieved Amount])
     FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.date <= t1.date) AS [Invested Amount]
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY t1.date
```